# Want to know the symptoms of a website on which we can bypass the login authentication(Directory traversal)

Tags: security, testing

When I typed the complete URL to a particular page section of a web app without logging in, it initially moved directly to the particular page without logging for 2 secs and before it gets completely loaded the page moves back to the login authentication page. can this app be bypassed without login authentication, can anyone clarify to me on this.

Comment: Sounds like it does, just try to stop the loading of the logging page using your browser stop button, or try running the page without javascript.

You can also write a simple script that ignores the redirect.

Comment: I tried the first two, tried browser stop button and tried running without javascript, the page stopped loading and became blank. I actually want to know whether without logging in and only using direct URL access can the web app be accessed or not, can you please kindly teach me the script that ignores the redirect or any link where I can learn that?.